# Identify GET and POST parameters in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the simplest way to identify and separate GET and POST parameters from a controller in Ruby on Rails, which will be equivalent to $_GET and $_POST variables in PHP?

Comment: I think the question is more 'given a request which has both POST data, and a query string' (which is entirely likely), how can you tell which parameters came from where? - Is this right?

Comment: I don't think he means he wants to separate the GET params from the POST params, but that the wants to get each parameter separately, whether it be GET or POST.  He basically wants the Rails equivalent to $_GET and $_POST from PHP.

Comment: @Brandon: Actually, I did mean what Orion Edwards said, but that was a long time ago. I now consider this a very stupid question. Albeit given the amount of views its still getting, many have not understood what I hadn't understood then.

Comment: then wouldn't Ben Scofield's answer be more appropriate to the question as you intended it?  Why isn't his the accepted answer?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't know of any convenience methods in Rails for this, but you can access the querystring directly to parse out parameters that are set there. Something like the following:

```
request.query_string.split(/&/).inject({}) do |hash, setting|
  key, val = setting.split(/=/)
  hash[key.to_sym] = val
  hash
end
```

Comment: Wow, why the downvotes? This answer solves the stated problem (unlike most of the other).

Comment: This is over the top; get?, post? or even request_method are much better options for determining the request type.

Comment: but... the question wasn't to determine the request type, and that isn't even close to what this code does. As I understood the question, it was (paraphrasing) "how do I retrieve parameters from get and post separately?"

Guess I'm just way off the mark with my reading comprehension...

Comment: From what Swanand (the asker) said to me above, it seems that this is really the best answer, and the down-voters should take back their downvotes.

Comment: I agree, and I changed the accepted answer. I should have done it sooner, but this was asked so long ago that it went out of reckoning.

Comment: @Ben Scofield: Thanks for the answer. +1 and enjoy your 'Nice Answer' badge. :-)

Comment: I initially downvoted this, but took it back.

The real question here is: Why in the world do you care if the parameters are GET or POST parameters? If you only support one or the other, alter your routes to only allow one or the other. If you're passing in both GET and POST parameters, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous by design and no one is *entitled* to an explanation. Best thing to do is shrug it off and move on.

Answer (score 54):

You can use the `request.get?` and `request.post?` methods to distinguish between HTTP Gets and Posts.

- See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html

Comment: The same link details how to get the parameters. That is what he is after.

Comment: They've changed site structure, so now this is the correct link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html

Comment: these methods are on the request. request.get? and request.post?

Answer (score 19):

You can do it using:

`request.POST`

and

`request.GET`

Answer (score 17):

There are three very-lightly-documented hash accessors on the request object for this:

- `request.query_parameters` - sent as part of the query string, i.e. after a ?
- `request.path_parameters` - decoded from the URL via routing, i.e. controller, action, id
- `request.request_parameters` - All params, including above as well as any sent as part of the POST body

You can use `Hash#reject` to get to the POST-only params as needed.

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/action_controller_overview.html section 9.1.1

I looked in an old Rails 1.2.6 app and these accessors existed back then as well.

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference between GET and POST params. A POST HTTP request can still have GET params.

GET parameters are URL query parameters.

POST parameters are parameters in the body of the HTTP request.

you can access these separately from the request.GET and request.POST hashes.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check the type of request in order to prevent doing anything when the wrong method is used, be aware that you can also specify it in your routes.rb file:

```
map.connect '/posts/:post_id', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'update', :conditions => {:method => :post}
```

or

```
map.resources :posts, :conditions => {:method => :post}
```

Your PostsController's update method will now only be called when you effectively had a post. Check out the doc for [resources](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.1.0/doc/index.html?a=M000354&name=resources).

Comment: You can also use :verify :method => :post etc. in a before filter.

Won't your second example break the index, new, edit, update, show & destroy actions in a RESTful controller?

Answer (score 4):

`request.get?` will return boolean true if it is GET method,

`request.post?` will return boolean true if it is POST method,

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do isn't very "Rails", if you know what I mean. Your GET requests should be **idempotent** - you should be able to issue the same GET request many times and get the same result each time.

Comment: That's not just a Rails thing - all well-behaved web applications should do that.

Comment: i do not understand actually. what is wrong with checking the request type, and getting the right set of params?

Comment: @mingyeow - Rails lets you ensure that certain actions respond to specific HTTP methods. In terms of overall application design this is a much better strategy than having parameters handled according to their origin.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know that level of detail in the controller. Your routes and forms will cause appropriate items to be added to the params hash. Then in the controller you just access say `params[:foo]` to get the foo parameter and do whatever you need to with it.

The mapping between GET and POST (and PUT and DELETE) and controller actions is set up in `config/routes.rb` in most modern Rails code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what Jesse Reiss is talking about is a situation where in your `routes.rb` file you have

```
post 'ctrllr/:a/:b' => 'ctrllr#an_action'
```

and you POST to **"/ctrllr/foo/bar?a=not_foo"** POST values **{'a' => 'still_not_foo'}**, you will have three different values of 'a': 'foo', 'not_foo', and 'still_not_foo'

'params' in the controller will have 'a' set to 'foo'. To find 'a' set to 'not_foo' and 'still_not_foo', you need to examine `request.GET` and `request.POST`

I wrote a gem which distinguishes between these different key=>value pairs at https://github.com/pdxrod/routesfordummies.

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.query_parameters().to_a.empty?
```