# Rails parameters from GET/POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fairly new to Rails and am writing a login form. I have used form_tag to pass through the user's submission to the account controller. Now, I don't want the user to be able to enter their login details through a GET request, so how can I check that a certain param is either a GET or POST parameter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also see answers to this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152585/identify-get-and-post-parameters-in-ruby-on-rails][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152585/identify-get-and-post-parameters-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Rails you don't have specific POST or GET parameters. You do have a POST or GET request. You can check it like this in your controller:

```
request.post?
```

or you can check for other HTTP verbs: GET, PUT and DELETE:

```
request.get?
request.put?
request.delete?
```

For more info, check this piece of the documentation: http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Request.html

Comment: In Rails parameters are always accessible through `params[:name]` no matter if they were POSTed or GETed.

Comment: The link is down, the official documentation was mover here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html

Answer (score 2):

If what you need is to know the HTTP verb you can ask directly to request:

```
request.request_method
```

Answer (score 0):

You could of course POST to a url that included a query parameter, so the selected answer might not be what you're looking for. Try checking if the parameter exists in the request arrays:

```
if request.GET.include? "param_name"
  # do something
end
```

There's also `request.POST` and there are aliases (`query_parameters` for `GET` and `request_parameters` for `POST`) for both in `ActionDispatch::Request`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-GET