# How to find the request type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use a conditional to run a statement based on the type of request, but there is no way I can reproduce the error in production to see what the request is, but I was thinking of doing it this way:

```
def save_path
    if request.method == 'GET'
        # don't save the timeout path or else the user has no obvious way to log in
        session[:desired_path] = request.url unless request.url =~ /#{timeout_path}$/
    end
end
```

So, basically I want to say if the request's method is a GET request then this line should run but don't know if my conditional is setup correctly or not. Any assistance on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails parameters from GET/POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023496/rails-parameters-from-get-post)

Answer (score 2):

You can check using a built in method:

```
request.get?
```

This answer to a similar question may be helpful for further info:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4023538/3435610