# What is the appropriate way to set up a route to transfer params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, parameters

I am trying to send the current params `@calc` to a `generate_csv` action.

How can I pass the params, so I can access them within the `generate_csv` action ?

**my view**

```
- form_tag generate_csv_path(@calc) do
  = submit_tag 'Print CSV'
```

**my routes:**

```
match '/generate_csv', :to => "main#generate_csv", :via => :post
resources :main
```

Which creates:

```
generate_csv POST   /generate_csv(.:format)  {:controller=>"main", :action=>"generate_csv"}
```

**my controller**

```
def generate_csv
  ..
```

**An Alternative:**

**my controller**

```
def generate_csv(foobar)
```

**my view**

```
- form_tag generate_csv_path(@calc) do
  = submit_tag 'Print CSV'
```

**the error**

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

How can that be if I'm obviously passing it a param? It seems its not accepting it.

Comment: did you try to pass it as a hidden field?

Comment: There's no use.. even if it was, it still wouldn't pass because no params pass when its clicked..

Comment: Great question. Its just a form_tag .. I might be semantically off. My scribbles above are literally the whole of most of the code in the form..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to 'Print Csv', generate_csv_path(:id => @calc) %>
```

But change you route, if your param is mandatory:

```
match '/generate_csv/:id', :to => "main#generate_csv"
```

Else:

```
match '/generate_csv/(:id)', :to => "main#generate_csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `params[:calc]` variable should help you within controller. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152585/identify-get-and-post-parameters-in-ruby-on-rails) may help you. Within your view just use normal form tags.

Comment: Nope, there's nothing in params. Its stark empty, except for the defaults.

Comment: well, are you sure you have soomething like `<input type="text" name="calc" />` inside your form? I'm sorry, i forgot to mention this: `params[whatever]` will give you access to the `whatever` variable, passed to your controller. So, you should define it before use, with GET (URL) or POST (form) methods.

Comment: yah the params are empty.. and the form is a default submit_tag where I am trying to send the instance_variable `@calc` which is available in the view the form is available in, and hoping to pass it to the `generate_csv` action..

Comment: wait...  you just said.... you are trying to send `@calc` to **form** or to **action**???

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I would like to take the instance variable @calc which is in the view that the form is in. And pass it through the form ( which is just a simple submit tag in a form tag ), to a controller action .

Answer (score 0):

`generate_csv_path(:calc => @calc)` should generate link `/generate_csv?calc=VALUE`

In controller you can access this value via params hash `params[:calc]`.

**p.s:** Recently I had a problem with params hash (ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0.3) which didn't receive query value from URL. It had only controller and action values. Switching from mongrel 1.2.rc to webrick did the trick.

Comment: Can you show the link which is generated with `generate_csv_path(:calc => @calc)`?