# Ruby on Rails 3: How to retrieve POST and GET params separately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, methods, get, request

I know you can get parameters using **params**, but the thing is that it merges all parameters whether they were sent via `GET` or `POST`:

If you send a request via `GET`, no problem, the parameters can only be squeezed in the URL.

But if you send a `POST` request that has a URL like `/blabla?foo=bar&foo2=bar2`, is there a way to tell the difference between the variables sent via the URL and the variables sent through the actual `POST` method?

Comment: Seems that similar question has been asked already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152585/identify-get-and-post-parameters-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: In that link, he asked how to get the request method. In my question I wanted to know how to tell the difference from a variable standpoint :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, in your controller you can get the GET parameters using request.GET and the POST parameters with request.POST

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't mention in the official guide.

Comment: Genius! Thank you! Everything always needs more and better documentation. But that's what StackOverflow is for. :)