# Ruby on Rails : How to retrieve POST and PATCH params only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, post, httprequest

So I want to do some modifications to the data only if it is a POST or a PATCH request. In this question ([Ruby on Rails 3: How to retrieve POST and GET params separatly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151391/ruby-on-rails-3-how-to-retrieve-post-and-get-params-separatly)), there is a way to get POST and GET params, but I've searched, and there doesn't seem to be a way to get PATCH data only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ActionDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) has a bunch of methods to check HTTP verb, those include: `get?`, `post?`, `patch?` and `put?`.

So the following should do the trick:

```
def some_action
  request.patch? # only patch requests
  # or
  request.request_method == :patch
  # and if you are intrested in both PATCH and POST... combine them!
  request.patch? || request.post?
end
```

Note that you might be intrested in restricting used HTTP verb at your routes definition. Defining your actions with a particular verb restricts requests which do not use the same verb from being processed:

```
# routes.rb
put '/orders/:id/refuse' => 'orders#refuse'
# so your refuse method accepts only PUT requests
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
# in some controller's method

if request.patch? || request.post?
  # do your work here
end
```

Comment: So if i access the params object inside the if statement, it's guaranteed that it will only have data that is either from PATCH or POST and no GET for example ?

Comment: @user2968505 exatly.